# How to generate a sf spatial data from the intersection with a raster data

Tags: r, geospatial, openstreetmap, spatial, r-raster

I have a **vector-type spatial data** file for the streets of a given municipality and another file with **raster-type spatial data** with the slope of the terrain.

My goal is to cross the two data to find out which stretches have the steepest streets.

If both were data of type sf, I would use the st_intersection function. But how to proceed when the data are of different types?

My ultimate goal is to generate spatial data in vector form with a column indicating the slope of that stretch.

*Reproducible example:*

```
library(elevatr) 
library(terra)
library(geobr)
library(osmdata) # package for working with streets

# 2 - get the municipality shapefile (vectorized spatial data)
municipality_shape <- read_municipality(code_muni = 3305802)

# 3 - get the raster topographical data
t <- elevatr::get_elev_raster(locations = municipality_shape, 
                              z = 10, prj = "EPSG:4674") 
obj_raster <- rast(t) 

# 4 - calculate the slope
aspect <- terrain(obj_raster, "aspect", unit = "radians")
slope <- terrain(obj_raster, "slope", unit = "radians")
hillshade <- shade(slope, aspect)

# 5 - get the streets data

getbb("Teresópolis")
big_streets <- getbb("Teresópolis") |>
  opq() |> # função que faz a query no OSM
  add_osm_feature(key = "highway", # selecionar apenas ruas
                  value = "primary") |> # característica das ruas
  osmdata_sf() # retorna a query como um objeto sf

# 6 - intersects the raster hillshade object with the sf object from streets available in big_streets$osm_lines$geometry.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to extract the streets, subset out the linestrings:

```r
big_streets <- getbb("Teresópolis")%>%
  opq()%>% # função que faz a query no OSM
  add_osm_feature(key = "highway", # selecionar apenas ruas
                  value = "primary") %>% # característica das ruas
  osmdata_sf() %>%
  osm_poly2line() %>%
  `[[`("osm_lines")
```

Now for each street, use `extract` to get the data corresponding to each linestring. You will need to average this so that there is a single average value for each street (though you could equally get the maximum slope if you wanted)

```r
big_streets$avg_shade <- sapply(big_streets$geometry, function(x) {
  mean(extract(hillshade, vect(x))[[2]])
})
```

Now `big_streets` has an extra column that gives you the average value of `shade` along each street. We can see what this looks like:

```r
ggplot(big_streets) + geom_sf(aes(color = avg_shade)) + scale_color_viridis()
```

[image]